# How to only change Pandas' series value when compared to elements from external list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, calculated-columns

I have a list of reference words to be retained in a column "columnName", if the values do not fall into the the elements of the `list_excluded`, then replace the value by "other". The following is something I have in mind:

```
list_excluded = ['egWord1', 'egWord2']

df['new'] = df['old']

# I only want to change values in 'new' column to 'other' if the value is not 'egWord1' or 'egWord2'
df.loc[df['new'] == 'other', df['columnName']] = list_excluded
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `apply()` for that like:

**Code:**

```
df['new'] = df['old'].apply(lambda x: 'other' if x in list_excluded else x)
```

**Test code:**

```
list_excluded = ['egWord1', 'egWord2']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ['egWord1', 'egWord2', 'XegWord1', 'YegWord2'], columns=['old'])

df['new'] = df['old'].apply(lambda x: 'other' if x in list_excluded else x)

print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
        old       new
0   egWord1     other
1   egWord2     other
2  XegWord1  XegWord1
3  YegWord2  YegWord2
```

Comment: instead of "in", I use "not in" which is my intent. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to do this without any sample data or desired output but it sounds like you're trying to select values that are not in the list, then set df['new'] to 'other'. Is that correct? If so, try this:

```
df.loc[~df['columnName'].isin(list_excluded), df['new']] = 'other'
```

This is assuming you've already done your lookup (the other answer has both steps in one).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly faster solution:

```
df['new'] = np.where(~df.old.isin(list_excluded), 'other', df.old)
```